# ASP.NET page_load is not firing in IFrame?

Tags: asp.net

In my asp.net web application,I use IFrames to show another page inside one page.But the problem is that the page load event of the embedded page in the IFrame is not firing when the Iframe is shown by clicking on a button in the parent page.I use the IFrame's visibility is true/false to show or hide the Iframe.I am confused what is happening there.Can somebody solve my problem....

Answer (score 0):

What page is the IFrame displaying?

Is it your ASP.NET page?

If it is a different page, you can not expect your Page_Load event to be fired. This is an ASP.NET event raised by the ASP.NET processing pipeline. If you load a different page to the IFrame, it will not raise your Page_Load event and there is no way it could.

You may want to learn about ASP.NET Page Lifecycle [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)

Comment: The page I'm trying to call is another asp page(page1.aspx) inside an Iframe in parent page page0.aspx

Comment: Do you set the url of the IFrame or only set it to visible? The IFrame will not reload when you are making it visible.

Comment: I'm setting the url and then making it visible

Answer (score 0):

> I use the IFrame's visibility is
>   true/false to show or hide the Iframe

If you're doing this using javascript then your IFrame has already loaded the page and it is just toggling to be visible true.